# Semantic Kernel Version 1.0.1

Tags: semantic-kernel

The latest version of Microsoft.SemanticKernel 1.0.1 is not supporting SKContext and SK Function Attribute. How to migrate from SK Context to Latest Version of 1.0.1.

How to migrate from SK Context to Latest Version of 1.0.1. Sample Code:

```
[SKFunction, SKName(nameof(Query)), Description("Request Process")]
public async Task <SKContext> ProcessRequest(SKContext context)
{
    //Migration Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `SKFunction` became `KernelFunction` and `SKContext` was renamed to `KernelArguments`. The first one is straightforward renaming, and if you want to explore more in-depth why and how `SKContext` turned into `KernelArguments`, you should explore the commits from the [dotnet-1.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/releases/tag/dotnet-1.0.0-rc1) release. I selected some of them:

- SkContext became [ContextVariables](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/pull/3666).
- ContextVariables became [KernelFunctionArguments](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/pull/3752)
- KernelFunctionArguments became [KernelArguments](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/pull/3769)

I recommend taking a look at the kernel syntax examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/tree/main/dotnet/samples/KernelSyntaxExamples). They use `KernelFunction` and `KernelArguments`. Example:

```cs
[KernelFunction]
[Description("Send email")]
public string SendEmail(
    [Description("target email addresses")]
    string emailAddresses,
    [Description("answer, which is going to be the email content")]
    string answer,
    KernelArguments arguments)
    {
    var contract = new Email()
    {
        Address = emailAddresses,
        Content = answer,
    };

    // for demo purpose only
    string emailPayload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(contract, this._serializerOptions);
    arguments["email"] = emailPayload;

    return "Here's the API contract I will post to mail server: " + emailPayload;
}
```

Finally, with want an example of an application using those abstractions, you should check the [chat-copilot](https://github.com/microsoft/chat-copilot) project.